# Trouble creating a model and it's children from an inlineformset_factory

Tags: python, django

I have a model for file uploads defined like this:

```
class UploadedFile(models.Model):
   fpath = models.FileField(...)
   sig   = models.CharField(max_length=32) # for md5 of data, computed with post_save
```

and I have another model, named MTest, that has this:

```
class MTest(models.Model):
  file1 = models.ForeignKey("UploadedFile",related_name="first_file")
  file2 = models.ForeignKey("UploadedFile",related_name="second_file")
  ... # other fields here
```

I want to show a form for `MTest`, and I want to allow the user to perform the upload of the files in 1 step. From what I read [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/modelforms/#inline-formsets) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/423437/how-to-save-inline-formset-models-in-django), I have this:

```
def x_attachment_t(request):
    c = {}

    MTestFormset = inlineformset_factory(UploadedFile, MTest, fk_name="file1",extra=1)

    c.update({"formset":MTestFormset})
    return render_to_response("form.html",c,context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

The problem is, I still get the data prepopulated for the file upload fields, and I only have a select box for the second file. Here's the code from the template:

```
    {% for form in formset.forms %}
        <div class="span-21 last">
            {% for field in form %}
                <font color="red">{{ field.errors }}</font>
                <div class="span-4">{{ field.label_tag }}</div>
                <div class="span-17">{{ field }}</div>
            {% endfor %}
        </div>
    {% endfor %}
```

For now, I'm blocked, and I don't know how to continue. I would appreciate any help :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your approach here isn't quite right. The inline formset is a pattern to "edit multiple `MTest`s linked to the same `UploadedFile`".

I would create a model forms for `UploadedFile` and `Mtest`. Exclude the `file1` and `file2` fields from the `MtestModelForm`. Put two uploaded file forms and the `MtestModelForm` in the same html `<form>` tag using the [`prefix`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/api/#django.forms.Form.prefix) argument.

Then in your view, if all three forms are valid, use save the `MtestModelForm` with [`commit=False`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/modelforms/#the-save-method), and update `file1` and `file2` before saving to the db.

Here's a skeleton of the view

```
def my_view(request):
    if request.method == "POST"
        file1_form = UploadedFileForm(request.POST, request.FILES, prefix="file1")
        file2_form = UploadedFileForm(request.POST, request.FILES, prefix="file2")
        mtest_form = MTestForm(data=request.POST, prefix="mtest")
        if mtest_form.is_valid() and file1_form.is_valid and file2_form.is_valid():
            file1 = file1_form.save()
            file2 = file2_form.save()
            mtest = mtest_form.save(commit=False)
            mtest.file1 = file1
            mtest.file2 = file2
            mtest.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect("/success-url/")
        # case for invalid form data or GET request omitted
```

Comment: What are you referring by `update file1 and file2 before saving to the db`? Do I need to take care of the relationship myself?

Comment: Yes, you explicitly set `file1` and `file2`. I've updated my answer with a sketch of the view.

Comment: Could you please show the code for the GET part? I'm not sure how to setup the prefixes in it.

Comment: It's the same as the POST part, but without any data e.g. `file1_form = UploadedFileForm(prefix="file1")`

Comment: thanks for correcting the typo. However, shouldn't the request.FILES also be passed?

Comment: Good spot, I had missed out `request.FILES`

Comment: Thanks for the help! It works nice now. Are there cases where I can use `inlineformset_factory` instead of the solution you presented?

Comment: Yes, `inlineformset_factory` is useful, but you need the foreign key to point from the model you want many of (e.g. `Book`) to the parent model (e.g `Author`). In this case, you have specified that there are two files for each `Mtest`, so the foreign key is pointing the other way,